# JW Player causes DOM7011 Error in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, jwplayer

In Internet Explorer using JW Player, I am receiving a DOM7011 error in the console. The code I have in place is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playerYeMZOkSByqDL').setup({
    file: 'http://s2.radioreformation.com:8050/;stream.mp3',
    image: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/radioreformation/playerlogo/fmwdunir.jpg',
    title: 'WDUN_IR',
    width: '200',
    height: '200',
    skin: 'bekle',
    autostart: 'true',
    primary: 'flash'
    });
</script>
```

I read that it might be a problem with caching, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer http://radioreformation.com/cdn_stream/player/?hash=JvKnrQWPsThuJteNQAuH

Comment: I don't get any console errors here at all in IE11.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I love this one! If you have the developer tools open in IE11 while viewing *any* page, even the simplest of barebones HTML, you will see that error message in the console. Try it yourself - create this page, and open it in IE11 with the console showing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Basic</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Page content.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In other words, the error means absolutely nothing and can be ignored. Microsoft's own documentation is instructive. Notice the last bullet on the list:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/dn265017(v=vs.85).aspx

In short, if the developer window is open, back navigation caching is disabled, and you'll get a DOM7011 warning. And it's a warning, not an error.